# Calling template function member of the base when it's called the same name

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand why the following code does not compile (using gcc 4.8.2):

```
struct A {
    template <typename T>
    T f() {return T(0);}
};

struct B : A {
    using MyT = int;
    MyT f() {return (A *)this->template f<MyT>();}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << b.f() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I change the name from `f` to `f1` in the base, then the following compiles just fine:

```
struct A {
    template <typename T>
    T f1() {return T(0);}
};

struct B : A {
    using MyT = int;
    MyT f() {return this->template f1<MyT>();}
};
```

Comment: Operator precedence.

Comment: To expand upon @T.C.'s comment: `return static_cast<A*>(this)->template f<MyT>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because operator precendence, you are casting result of `f` function to `A*`, instead of cast `this` to `A*` and it's actually better to use `static_cast`.

```
MyT f() {return static_cast<A*>(this)->f<MyT>();}
```

this will work. And also you have name hiding, you just do this:

```
struct B : A {
    using MyT = int;
    using A::f;
    MyT f() {return this->f<MyT>();}
};
```

Comment: Thanks! In the last piece, it works even without `this->`.

Comment: Hmm... The second suggestion does not work for my actual code. The call `static_cast<const Base *>(this)->template successors<Neighbor>()` works, but the call `successors<Neighbor>()` does not even though I have `using Base::successors;`...